# Issue while creating iOS build of a Unity project, Agora sdk is most likely creating issue

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, build, agora

We have integrated Agora in our app using this
https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora_Unity_WebGL

Agora is used for streaming audio, video and screensharing. We have tested it on multiple platforms WebGL and android. It's working fine, but whenever we create build in x-code we are getting this list of errors.

```
Undefined symbol: _clearRemotePositions
Undefined symbol: _enableRemoteSuperResolution3
Undefined symbol: _enableRemoteSuperResolution4
Undefined symbol: _localSpatialAudio_initialize
Undefined symbol: _localSpatialAudio_release
Undefined symbol: _localSpatialAudio_setParameters
Undefined symbol: _muteAllRemoteAudioStreams_spatialAudio
Undefined symbol: _muteLocalAudioStream_spatialAudio
Undefined symbol: _removeRemotePosition
Undefined symbol: _setAudioRecvRange
Undefined symbol: _setDistanceUnit
Undefined symbol: _setMaxAudioRecvCount
Undefined symbol: _updateRemotePosition
Undefined symbol: _updateSelfPosition
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```